# Weird Oracle 11g JDBC driver error under JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: oracle11g, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I got the following exception while using oracle as database in my application.
The warn occurs randomly, even in server startup. If the database is empty, when it came up, this warn appers and the db generation fail for some tables.

I don't have any idea of what's going on here.

Thanks in advance

```
4:27:47,263 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException 
at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:709) 
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)     
at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.recover(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:162)  
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:503) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:] 
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:471) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:] 
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:385) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:] 
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]  
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]  
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
```

Comment: correct log formatting & use code block instead of quote for code parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to fix this.

Based on [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ARJUNA016027LocalXARecoveryModulexaRecoveryGotXAExceptionXAExceptionXAERRMERR), I've done the following as admin:

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_pending_transactions TO carlos;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.pending_trans$ TO carlos;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_2pc_pending TO carlos;
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_system TO carlos;
```

The warn disappear, but I don't know exactly which are the consequences of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

For security concerns related to execute privileges on sys.dbms_system, see http://database-diva.com/blog/?p=6.

Comment: No, I don't.  (Sorry for the delayed response.)

Comment: Link is currently dead.